# Is there any efficient way to make a shortcut to an Apple Book?

Tags: siri, books, shortcuts-app

While you can make shortcuts, Home Screen shortcuts and ask Siri to do things like play a specific song or open a certain URL, I do not know of any ways to open a specific book. Is there any way to quickly open a specific book, while you are working on something in a certain app?